# How to Office Script for saving selected contents to another sheet and then Paste from Clipboard?

Tags: excel, office365-apps

How to write Office Script to save selected Excel cells to next rows of another Worksheet and then paste from Clipboard?

I need this because of lost Undo items; probably due to AutoSave which is set to OFF for Freezing risk.

APPENDIX
[Excel - Freeze during autosave](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-freeze-during-autosave/6d5fa58b-cf04-48ee-ac86-b567e67edf2d)

Comment: Please edit to show your work (code/script, data, expected vs actual outputs, etc). As written, there's nothing shown except a requirement (and really this seems like it's better suited for SuperUser)

Comment: Oh and this doesn't seem related at all to [tag:javascript]

Comment: This question arose because Undo sometimes did not work for Excel Web when AutoSave was OFF. I can check again but pretty sure Excel Web Versioning is not possible when AutoSave is OFF. Without Versioning, Undo becomes important especially when I need to switch back and forth between Desktop and Web for same Workbook (to use some Excel features such as Name Manager). Unfortunately Undo fail sometimes, I cannot raise a Ticket to Tech Support. I wonder if there is an alternative such as Excel Script to automatically Save to say, a Helper Sheet?